# Настройки сервера для UMI

Tags: php, ubuntu, apache, umi

*UMI 2.7.4.*

Цитата из документации:

> При тестировании UMI.CMS выдержала более миллиона запросов в сутки на простом однопроцессорном сервере P4-1600 1G RAM, при этом работая параллельно с десятками других сайтов.

А вот у меня тормозит. Сервер около 4 секунд думает, и только потом начинает отдавать контент.

Вот [тест](http://www.webpagetest.org/result/150806_SC_B4V/)

Железо:

- Intel Atom CPU D2550 @ 1.86GHz - 2c/4t
- 2x2GB DDR3 1066 MHz
- HDD: 2 TB
- Apache 2 в режиме mod_php
- PHP 5.5.9
- MySQL 5.5.43

Стоит *gzip* и все модули, которые перечислены в документации.

Сервер, можно сказать, простаивает (*load average* ~0.25) и на тестируемом сайте посетителей около 20 человек в сутки.

Из косяков:

Нельзя включить акселератор (пробовал *memcache* и *apc*), так как от предыдущего программиста досталась кривая система деления *БД* для одной админки, поэтому шаблоны начинают путаться.

И не хочет включаться статическое кэширование, т.е. выставляю галочку, сохраняю → галочка пропала.

В планах на фронт поставить *nginx*, но не думаю, что это сильно спасет ситуацию.

Comment: решайте проблему с кэшированием — и будет вам «миллион запросов в сутки». ну, по крайней мере, не все страницы будут генерироваться при **каждом** обращении, как происходит сейчас.

Comment: Сейчас вообще нет запросов, а такая задержка. Здесь в чем-то другом проблема.

Comment: как нет? вы же сами пишете: делаете запрос к сайту. и через четыре секунды получаете ответ. для сложного и перегруженного функциональностью фреймворка, которым является umi, мне кажется, это вполне нормально. а вот последующие запросы к сайту должны воспользоваться частью уже кэшированной информации и выполняться значительно быстрее. но у вас кэширование отключено. и потому каждый запрос к сайту выполняется «с чистого листа».

Comment: но отчасти вы правы: вполне вероятно, что присутствуют ещё какие-то проблемы, которые вносят свою лепту в общее время отклика. но я бы, столкнувшись с подобной ситуацией, первым делом наладил бы работу php-кэширования. а дальше уже искал других виновников.

Comment: К сожалению, кэширование я буду налаживать в последнюю очередь, т.к. предыдущий программист переписал мультисайтовость на свой лад. Он видимо и не подозревал, что нужно было сначала полностью протестировать свое решение. Я с вами согласен, но сейчас сервер полностью простаивает и отдан на растерзание UMI и в итоге имеем такую отвратную производительность.

Comment: может быть, мы вкладываем разный смысл в слово «кэширование»? я говорю о php-кэшировании. а вы, видимо, о кэше http-сервера.

Answer (score 1):

> Нельзя включить акселератор (пробовал memcache и apc)

а надо бы.

без кэширования информации интерпретатор при **каждом** запросе, выполняя *php*-код сайта, вновь и вновь производит инициализацию мегабайт информации.

время этой инициализации и составляет, скорее всего, **львиную** долю тех самых «четырёх секунд раздумий».

но, вполне возможно, есть и другие «непроизводительные» задержки, с которыми, мне кажется, стоит разбираться **после** устранения причины **основной** задержки.